# How to Save Upcoming date in string

Tags: java, date, calendar

How to get upcoming date in string ... (like 17 April 2020 or 2015)
(comparing cuurenttime and futuretime)
here is the what i am trying...

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");      
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String currenttime = new String(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
String futuretime = new String (dateFormat.format(__________); //how to store future date if i have the current date
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: What do you mean by upcoming/future date?

Comment: means date after current date like... 17 april 2014 or 2020 ... @asgs

Comment: If you can know the difference in milli seconds from now and the future date, `dateFormat.format(cal.getTime() + <diff>)` would do. But I guess you're better off manipulating with the `Calendar` instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's like current time:

```
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 3);//A date in future (achieved somehow)
String currenttime = new String(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
String futuretime = new String (dateFormat.format(cal2.getTime()));
```

---

Note: as OP said in the comments he/she wants to compare the dates, and it's really a bad idea to compare two dates in string formats and I suggest you to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Are you saying to save static future ...?
i am trying it to compare with current...
not can be Dynamic... (if current == future after 1 year ??? )

Comment: @user3467110 Please explain more. I answered "how to store ...". Do you want to compare two dates?

Comment: yeah i want to compare... actually ( :) )